# Not getting id from URL in Laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-6

I am very new in laravel and trying to get id from URL **example.com/cmsedit/3** but failing.

My routes:-

```
Route::get('cmsedit/{id}', function($id)
{
    return view('admin.cmsed');
});
```

when I am trying to get an ID in my view file

```
<?PHP echo $id ?>
```

It says `Undefined variable: id` and if I am using `$request->id` it is also throwing an error `Undefined variable: request`

Laravel version = 6

Comment: you need to return view with data like `return view('admin.cmsed',['id' => $id]);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should return the given ID from Router's callback:

```
Route::get('cmsedit/{id}', function($id) {
    return view('admin.cmsed', ['id' => $id]);
});
```

or,

```
Route::get('cmsedit/{id}', function($id) {
    return view('admin.cmsed', compact('id'));
});
```